# ADB doesn't work...Eclipse doesn't detect my device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, driver, adb

I have a problem with the adb. I have the adb drivers installed and even in the device manager my phone is shown when connected. But when I want to use my phone to test my apps via USB Debugging it doesn't work (USB debugging is activated). I also used the command prompt to execute "adb devices" but no devices are shown.

Comment: restart adb and eclipse

Comment: Are you on windows or linux? If you are on Windows, make sure you install the Google USB driver via SDK Manager. If you using Samsung device, install the Samsung android driver if eclipse does not detect the phone after USB driver installation

Comment: or use a third party app like moboquick or mobogenie

Comment: What device are you using? Do you have the driver installed (Windows)? Have you accepted the certificate after the device said it was connected and asked for it?

Comment: I am working under windows. I installed the USB driver via SDK Manager. Where do I finde the samsung android driver? I am using the Galaxy S3!

Comment: Now I installed "SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones". But still the same problem:(

Comment: Maybe another important information. My phone is not shown on "My computer".

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the `USB Driver`.

Find your device in the `Device Manager`, right-click on it and select `Update Device Software`, choose `Browse my computer for driver software`, navigate to the sdk folder (in my case it's under `C:\Android`):

`C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

and finish the installation.

**EDIT:** Also you may need to click on `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer` - when you have navigated to this folder you should see `Android Composite ADB Interface` - select it and finish the installation this way if the above does not work.

Comment: then make sure you have installed the correct Android SDK (check the Android SDK Manager) - if you have a device with API 19 and your latest SDK is API 18 this might cause the problem.

Comment: I have installed API 17, 18, 19.

Comment: which API level is your device?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to manually enter a value in your adb_usb.ini file. On Windows, that can be done with:

```
echo 0xYYYY >> "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini"
```

where YYYY is the 4-digit Vendor ID for your device. (That's easy to get with `lsusb` on Linux, but I don't know how to determine it on Windows.)

You'll need to then restart ADB with:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

Comment: If you've enabled USB debugging, installed the correct drivers, added an adb_usb.ini entry, and restarted ADB, then it should work. Another thing to try is to change the mount type (file sharing, camera, etc.); I've seen reports that some types of mounting causes issues.

Comment: One other possibility is a defective cable. I once had a cable that had an intermittent problem that interfered with ADB even though it seemed to work OK when for mounting a drive. Perhaps ADB gave up after X number of errors?